# UIColecctionView with Sections [SWIFT] IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi People (Sorry for my English)

I have a problem. I want to create the next UI

[image]

I have a UIViewController It has a UITableView with a custom cell. This Custom cell has a UIImage, UILabel and UICollectionView.

My Problem begin here, in the UICollectionView

My UICollectionView has UILabel that represent a Sub Title and several buttons. one Sub Title has many buttons.

I already made this UI. I got the size buttons I got the width screen and I calculated the quantity of buttons that I can put by row. I also calculated
the sum of heigh of the Sub Titles and rows buttons and I set UICollectionView heigh, because I need to see all the items inside it.

I think that can be improved, because my code result is very confused.

My button has a constant width. I want to set my UICollectionView for that it will has a title section and rows buttons and the buttons change the row when the remaining space in the row is minor to width button.

Thanks :]

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far?

Comment: Joseph, for best results on Stack Overflow make sure your questions follows [mcve]